# How can I expand a list in a Toolbar in QML when the user tap the title of the it?

Tags: qt, qml

I want to perform the expansion action in the ToolBar when the user taps on the title of it, as in the pictures that I attach.

When the user touches the title of the toolbar then you should see a list of the filters that you can apply.

You have any ideas on how to implement this action in QML?

[image: toolbar_defaultState]

[image: toolbar_expand]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty easy. Copy the following in the awesome [QML web editor](https://qmlweb.github.io/):

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Column {
    width: 500

    Rectangle {
        id: toolbar
        width: parent.width
        height: 50
        Text {
            text: "Elenco"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            font.pointSize: 24; font.bold: true
        }
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: listBox.visible = !listBox.visible
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: listBox
        color: "gray"
        width: parent.width
        visible: false
        height: 200
        Column {
            width: parent.width

            Repeater {
                model: 4
                delegate:
                    Rectangle {
                        width: parent.width
                        color: index % 2 ? "#C9D6DE" : "#E7F6FF"
                        height: 50
                        Text { anchors.centerIn: parent; text: "Persona " + (index + 1) }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This work and the idea is good. It's just that I can not hang up the list you crate below the toolbar @Massimo Callegari

Comment: What ? Mine is just an example. In a real implementation the Repeater I used should be a ListView with a proper model provided